# Update sql-command string from c# ExecuteNonQuery();

Tags: c#, sql-server, string

App works but UPDATE through WPF does not work

```
string sqlIns = "UPDATE Team_table SET result1 = '4:2' where name1=@Team1 and name2=@Team1";    
string Team1_string = Team1.Text;
```

// Team1, Team2, result1, result2 is the name of TextBox controls

```
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team1", Team1_string);
string Team2_string = Team2.Text;
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team2", Team2_string);
string result1_string = Result1.Text;
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result1", result1_string);
```

How to do it work?

Comment: Are you sure you don't a mistake between "@Team1" and "@Team2", "@result1". Your update command string contains one parameters : "@Team1". Check your code.

Comment: "Nice" names for variables, they driving me crazy. Especially, this one - `TTKZS`. Also, why don't use `using` for disposables?

Comment: No, there no mistake and ther is always hhconn. No ttkzs. )) This is from the past

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are updating the rows when teams play themselves the error is from:

```
name1=@Team1 and name2=@Team1
```

I am fairly cofident you ment for that to be

```
name1=@Team1 and name2=@Team2
```

Comment: I Agree With you. Great Point :)

Comment: :) Great I'm just waiting for the one who asked this Question.Okay let me do it.

Comment: But in SQL SERVER this works. For ex: UPDATE Team_table SET result1 = '6:2' where name1='Team1' and name2='Team2'

Comment: How to do it thhrough WPFTextbox via C#?

Comment: You made a typo, just fix it like I showed you, just replace `name2=@Team1` with `name2=@Team2` in the string `sqlIns` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting connection string to SqlConnection Object properly

**Replace this :**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(TTKZS);
```

**with following :**

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(hhconn);
```

Comment: Yes, I see, i remade connection when post this message. Error is not from this. Sorry